# Comprobar si varios valores estan en una lista de python

Tags: python, lista, if

Tengo una lista de enteros llamada `MsgID` y quiero hacer un If donde comprueba si dentro de esa lista hay algun valor mayor que 3. Mi intento:

```
if [3,2,1,0] not in MsgID:
    pass
```

Tambien he probado con

```
if MsgID > 3:
     pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa la funcion [`Any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```
>>> MsgID = [3,2,1,0]
>>> any(i > 3 for i in MsgID)
False

>>> MsgID2 = [3,2,1,0, 4]
>>> any(i > 3 for i in MsgID2)
True
```

[Demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMOGdPWUhOOG5TYWs)

En tu código:

```
if any(i > 3 for i in MsgID):
    pass
```